# How to get group radio button Value using Code ingnitor in the controller

Tags: php

I have two radio button

```
<input tabindex="3" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="M">Male&nbsp;<input tabindex="4" type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="F">Female
```

How to get group radio button Value using Code ingnitor

```
$this->input->post("gender");
```

I want to retrieve selected radio button value as "M" or "F"
In the controller side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input tabindex="3" type="radio" name="gender[]" id="gender" value="M">Male
<input tabindex="4" type="radio" name="gender[]" id="gender" value="F">Female

$this->input->post('gender')
```

Thanks
Sanil

Comment: its gives array not a value as M or F

Comment: not a blank array , array with selected value $gender[0] as M, but i want direct value

Comment: Array ( [gender] => Array ( [0] => M ) )  something like this??

Comment: try this instead $this->input->post('gender[0]');

Comment: $this->input->post('gender[0]'); this gives incorrect value as 0 rather than selected one